# Return 'X' when sum of 9 digits divided by 11 is 10

Tags: java, methods, char, append, symbols

In my code, I want `charSum` to return `'X'` if the remainder is 10 when the sum of 9 digits is divided by 9. I tried both `charSum = 'X'` and `charSum = (char) 88` and neither works. Something in my algorithm must be wrong. Please help.

```
public static char getCheckSum(String isbn) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
        int[] num = new int[isbn.length()]; 
        num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(i));
        sum = sum + num[i];
    }
    int last = (sum % 11);
    char charSum;
    if (last == 10){
        charSum = 'X';
    } else {
        charSum = (char) (last + 48);
    }
    return charSum;
}

public static String formatISBNWithHyphens(String isbn) {
    // original isbn:       123456789
    // possible new isbn:   1-234-56789-X
    char isbn10 = getCheckSum(isbn);
    String isbn10Str = isbn + Character.toString(isbn10);

//  char[] c = new char[isbn10Str.length()];    *leaving this here for future learning.
    String[] cStr = new String[isbn10Str.length()];
    String isbnStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < isbn10Str.length(); i++){
        cStr[i] = Character.toString(isbn10Str.charAt(i));
//      c[i] = isbn10Str.charAt(i);             *leaving this here for future learning.
        if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 8 ) {
            cStr[i] += '-';
         }

         isbnStr += cStr[i];
    }
    return isbnStr;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine. If I run it with `933456789` (the sum of which is 54, so 54 % 11 = 10), the `getCheckSum()` method returns `X` as expected.

**However**, this does not seem like the correct way to calculate an ISBN-10 checksum. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10_check_digits):

> The 2001 edition of the official manual of the International ISBN
>   Agency says that the ISBN-10 check digit – which is the last digit of
>   the ten-digit ISBN – must range from 0 to 10 (the symbol X is used for
>   10), and must be such that the sum of all the ten digits, each
>   multiplied by its (integer) weight, descending from 10 to 1, is a
>   multiple of 11.

I've implemented it according to the specification as follows:

```
public static char getCheckDigit(String isbn) {
    if (isbn == null || !isbn.matches("[0-9]{9,}")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal ISBN value");
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        sum += ((10 - i) * Character.digit(isbn.charAt(i), 10));
    }

    int check = ((11 - (sum % 11)) % 11);

    return check == 10 ? 'X' : Character.forDigit(check, 10);
}
```

Applied to a couple of ISBN values I found on the same Wikipedia page:

```
getCheckDigit("097522980"); // --> returns 'X'
getCheckDigit("094339604"); // --> returns '2'
getCheckDigit("999215810"); // --> returns '7'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static char getCheckSum(String isbn) {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < isbn.length(); i++) {
        int[] num = new int[isbn.length()]; 
        num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(num[i]);
        sum = sum + num[i];
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    int last = (sum % 11);
    char charSum;
    if (last == 10){
        charSum = 'X';
    } else {
        charSum = (char) (last + 48);
    }
    return charSum;
}


     public static void main(String []args){
          String isbn="123456787";
    // possible new isbn:   1-234-56789-X
    char isbn10 = getCheckSum(isbn);

        System.out.println(isbn10);


     }
}
```

it's working fine :)